# Error occurring with apt

Tags: apt, upgrade

```
sudo apt-get update –fix-missing

sudo apt-get update –fix-missing
```

> E: The update command takes no arguments

What's going on?

Comment: What Linux distribution are you running and what are you trying to install?

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by the error message, `update` doesn’t accept any arguments:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

is the appropriate command to update your repository indexes.

To fix a broken install, use `install`:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```